# How to convert "20120111141311Z" into yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss +/- hh:mm

Tags: javascript, date

I am getting date value in format "20120111141311Z".

I want to convert the above value into `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss +/- hh:mm` format.

Don't know how to do it. I tried with Date() function, it is giving NaN.

Comment: In what language? FORTRAN? COBOL?

Comment: Probably Javascript. But confirmation would be nice :P

Comment: Remove the Z, add some dashes, some colons, a space, and "+0000".

Comment: I am looking for a solution in JavaScript.

Comment: try with the jquery plugin datejs, or review the code and create your custom JS http://www.datejs.com/. This Plugin have the Parse function wich convert a DateTime in a String specific format.

Comment: Probably you need to use *subString* to collect the parts. Or *split* and join some together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem using below code

```
       zuluDate: function(value){
           if (value) {
           var year = value.substring(0,4);
        var month = value.substring(4,6);
        var date = value.substring(6,8);
        var hour = value.substring(8,10);
        var min = value.substring(10,12);
        var sec = value.substring(12,14);
        return new Date(year, month-1, date, hour, min, sec);
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone for posting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing of date strings using the Date constructor is largely implementation dependent and not reliable. All you want to do is reformat a string, so split it into parts and do that, e.g.:

```
function formatString(s) {
  var b = s.match(/\d\d/g);
  if (b) {
    return b[0] + b[1] + '-' + b[1] + '-' + b[2] + ' ' +
           b[3] + ':' + b[4] + ':' + b[5] + '+0000';
  }
}
```

You can do a similar thing using [*substring*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.15), but match is simpler I think. The timezone is +0000 since you've specified Z. It's not difficult to deal with actual offsets.